# symfony 3 - generate current url with different locales

Tags: php, routes, locale, symfony

What I want to do is create a language switcher template which outputs a list of links, like so:

```
<div class="language-switcher">
    <ul>
        {% for locale in allowed_locales %}
            <li>
                <a href="{{ path($get current route name here $, { '_locale': locale }) }}">
                    {{ locale|upper }}
                </a>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

The main problem I'm having is - Twig's built-in `path` function accepts a route NAME, which there seems to be no way of retrieving in Symfony 3.

The other problem is - the route might have additional parameters, which need to be merged with the _locale parameter. From the code I've found on the internet (all for symfony v2, of course), making this work makes for very ugly code which definitely does not belong in a template.

I think the best way to achieve this is to make a Twig extension with a new route generation function for this purpose, but it seems that might be problematic as well because the path() function is located in another extension, which I don't know how to access from my own extension (and I'm not so sure it's a good idea either).

How could I make this thing?

Edit: I also don't want to pass the data to the template in each action because that's not DRY at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a fairly short and simple solution: make a localized version of the path()/url() Twig functions, which auto-detects the current route and attempts to find a localized version of it and replace the _locale parameter.

https://gist.github.com/jurchiks/3b4e1bd249d7e8c1b60e

Essentially, you have something like this template somewhere in header or footer:

```
<h1>Current language: {{ app.request.getLocale() }}</h1>
<div class="language-switcher">
    <ul>
        {# allowed_locales comes from config #}
        {% for locale in allowed_locales %}
            <li>
                <a href="{{ localized_path('__current__', locale) }}">
                    {{ locale|upper }}
                </a>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you can do this:

```
<a href="{{ localized_path('route_name') }}">
```

And it will output that specific route in current locale.

With a route like this:

```
@Route("/", name="home")
@Route("/{_locale}/", name="home_lang", requirements={"_locale"="%allowed_locales%"})
public function indexAction()
...

@Route("/{_locale}/foo/", name="foo", requirements={"_locale"="%allowed_locales%"})
public function fooAction()
...
```

If you open `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`, it will output `Current language: en`, `/en/, /ru/, /tk/`. For fooAction(), only explicit locale is allowed, and the output is the same.
Obviously, explicit locale will be set correctly, this is done by the route matcher in Symfony.

Answer (score 7):

@jurchick's link to the `localized_path` function no longer works, so I whipped up a pure-Twig implementation:

```
{% set req = app.request %}
{% for locale in allowed_locales %}
    {% if locale != req.getLocale() %}
        <link rel="alternate" hreflang="{{ locale }}" href="{{
            absolute_url(
                path(
                    req.attributes.get('_route'),
                    req.attributes.get('_route_params')|merge({'_locale': locale})
                )
            ) }}" />
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

This block actually generates alternate language links for the current page. Feel free to use it in your base HTML block.

Comment: Haven't used Symfony since this question, pretty much hate it now. But perhaps someone else will find it useful.

Comment: @jurchiks probably just me in the future, when I've forgotten how to do this!

Comment: @jurchiks only a small mistake in `req..attributes.get` (double points), but it works fine, thanks :)

Comment: @aalaap Any idea on how to do this in Symfony 4?

Comment: @marcuse they still haven't implemented this??

Comment: @marcuse I haven't worked with Symfony since 2.8, so I'm not sure! Sorry!

Comment: Solution for Symfony 4+ [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51597719/manually-switch-locale-in-symfony-4/51649342#51649342) !

Answer (score 1):

How about having a route action which changes the locale then redirects back to the orginal page via the referer in the request header (this will get your previous url):

```
public function localeChangerAction(Request $request, $locale)
{
    return $this->redirect($request->headers->get('referer'));
}
```

This is untested but I have impletmented this before - I've just tapped this out on my mobile from memory.

I did implement the 'sticky' locale from the cookbook to handle the locale switch:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/session/locale_sticky_session.html

This may help you out, it'll work for all routes!

Comment: That doesn't set the new locale in the URL.

Comment: Eh, I guess that will have to do. Didn't want to have 2 redirects instead of 1, but damn, this thing is not very flexible.

Comment: I doubt that my client will accept this solution though, because the end result means that there will be one url (/path/to/something/) for all languages, which means users can't share a page in their desired language and everyone has to manually change the language if they need it.
I wanted the URLs to be `/en/path/to/smth/`, `/ru/path/to/smth/` with implicit `en` if no language prefix, but it seems there is no reliable way to guess the name of the localized route if a user has opened the non-localized one.

Comment: Once the sticky locale is in place you can set multiple paths for the same action - one with the _locale parameter and one without

Comment: That's not the point. Your code does not redirect from `/path/to/smth/` to `/en/path/to/smth/`. Besides that - even with 2 routes, it is still possible to set the language to any of the allowed and keep accessing `/path/to/smth/` with all of those languages. This is not SEO-friendly.

Comment: I'm currently building a multilingual cms with tranlatable dymanic urls - I've had to write a custom route matcher as I've found symfonys router quite ridged when it comes to dymanic urls with translatable entities. Luckly this is a new systen rather than building on an existing one, so currenty all my routes/paths go through the same action which sorts out the locale and redirects/refreshes  if necessary. It did take a bit if messing around check translations to find the correct locale but I did get direct links to work in my case

Comment: Sounds like it took you quite a bit of work to get it done, and seems like I'll have to do the same... Fun.

Comment: Yeah... I had to rebuild it twice before I eventually nailed it! Goodluck!

Comment: just a thought - but if you use my above answer but add the locale to the url would that get you closer to you goal - like :      return $this->redirect($locale."/".$request->headers->get('referer'));

Comment: But you can't be sure that the referer isn't a full URL. Or that the locale is even the first parameter.

Comment: Anyway, I already have a solution: https://gist.github.com/jurchiks/3b4e1bd249d7e8c1b60e With this code, you can have Routes without a _locale parameter and an implicit default (which is set by the framework to config.yml framework.default_locale), or an explicit locale with your requirements. Results: /foo/bar/ - locale EN, /ru/foo/bar/ - locale RU.